# Write a column next to list in csv_python

Tags: python, list, csv, multiple-columns, writer

I have two lists, when I print them separately using:

```
writer.writerows(list_)
```

I get

list_1:

```
0   -0.00042    0.004813    0.010428    0.051006
1   0.000053    0.004531    0.010447    0.051962
2   0.000589    0.004518    0.009801    0.052226
3   0.000083    0.004581    0.010362    0.052288
4   -0.000192   0.003726    0.011258    0.051094
5   0.000281    0.004078    0.01008     0.052156
```

list_2:

```
-0.000419554    -0.000366128    0.000223134     0.000306416     0.000114709
```

It's been a whole day I've been trying to add list_2 as another column to list_1 and write them to a csv file. I thought it was straightforward but have stuck. I appreciate any help.

Comment: So, is list_1 a list of lists?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Are the elements of list_2 supposed to be written as a new row, or is each element supposed to be written at the end of one of the rows for list_1? What do you want to happen if there aren't enough elements in list_2? This example shows five elements in list_2 and six rows for list_1.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thought appending list_2 to list_1 could help which didn't. Used writerow(list1+list2), writing them separately to file, added both lists to a new list and used zip function. but none helped.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper actually both list have same number of elements, and yes lis_2 elements are to be added at the end of each row in lis_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, not knowing what your data look like, so I have to guess:

```
list_1 = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
]
list_2 = [10,20,30]

list_1 = [row + [col] for row, col in zip(list_1, list_2)]
for row in list_1:
    print row
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 10]
[4, 5, 6, 20]
[7, 8, 9, 30]
```

Now that list_1 has list_2 as a new column, you can use the csv module to write it out.

Comment: Thanks Hai Vu. Did the job!

Comment: Note that this and any other solution using `zip` will truncate to the shorter list if they are not of equal length.  Comments say they are equal,  so that may not matter,  but the example lists differ in length.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, btw, what function should be used when lists are not of the same size?

Comment: That's `izip_longest` :)

Answer (score 3):

A general solution which combines columns from two lists of lists (or other iterables):

```
import csv
import itertools
import sys

def combine_columns(iterable1, iterable2):
    for x, y in itertools.izip(iterable1, iterable2):
        yield list(x) + list(y)

list1 = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23]]
list2 = [[14, 15], [24, 25]]
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerows(combine_columns(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
11,12,13,14,15
21,22,23,24,25
```

Comment: I would probably do this with just a generator expression rather than a new generator definition: `writer.writerows(list(x) + list(y) for (x, y) in itertools.izip(list_1, list_2))`. But points for generality.

Comment: Why do I get 'TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable' using this code?

Comment: @PyLearner Use 2D arrays, not just flat arrays. For example: `numpy.array([[14, 15], [24, 25]], dtype=numpy.float64)`

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 So, this means I cannot add a list like `list_=[10,20,30]` using this method because `itertools` cannot iterate on that? Anyway, this `izip` method survived me at another part of my code. Many thanks :)